# Forbidden(403) permission access error on Apache2.4 on windows machine

Tags: windows, apache-2.4, python, django

I am running my Django app on Apache2.4.38. I have given all the necessary parameters and access to the Apache server. Still, I am receiving a 403 error when I try to access the Application URL.

**httpd-vhosts.conf:**

```
Listen 8084
WSGIPythonPath "D:/WebAttendance/"
<VirtualHost *:8084>

 SSLEngine on
 SSLCertificateFile "D:/Desktop/Python/WebAttendance/certs/development.crt"
 SSLCertificateKeyFile "D:/Desktop/Python/WebAttendance/certs/development.key"

    WSGIScriptAlias / "D:/Desktop/Python/WebAttendance/WebAttendance/wsgi.py"
 DocumentRoot "D:/Desktop/Python/WebAttendance"

    <Directory "D:/Desktop/Python/WebAttendance/">
     <Files wsgi.py>
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
     </Files>
    </Directory>

    <Directory "D:/Desktop/Python/WebAttendance/home/static/">
 Require all granted
 </Directory>
    Alias /static "D:/Desktop/Python/WebAttendance/home/static"

    ErrorLog "D:/Desktop/Python/WebAttendance/log/error.log"
 CustomLog "D:/Desktop/Python/WebAttendance/log/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

**Error:**

> Forbidden 
>   You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Comment: The HTTP [`403 Forbidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) response status code indicates that the server understands the request but refuses to authorize it.